# How to add time to directions in Bing Maps v7 API?

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I am trying to work through this example in Bing Maps v7 API:

[Create Driving Route Example](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Isdk/AjaxV7#DirectionsModule2)

What I would like to do is to add a starting time to the example and have each direction have the time you should reach the point.  For example 08:00 Start at Airport, 08:15, 32 miles Turn Right, 08:30 64 miles Finish at Hotel.

I have searched through the documentation but cannot find anything like this.

I have noticed that some distances in the directions get assigned times as well as the distance.  How is this controlled?

If this isn't possible, can you tell me where I can find the documentation as to how to format each direction and control what is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Directions module in the Bing Maps V7 control does not have a method to take in a future date time for driving routes. However the Bing Maps REST routing service does support this for driving routes. The REST services are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx You will want to use the dateTime parameter. The documentation says that this is require for transit, but doesn't highlight that this is also an option for driving. When set predictive traffic data is used to approximate the travel time. It won't tell you what time you will arrive somewhere, but will tell you how long it would take which you could easily add to your start time. If you want to use this with the JavaScript map control, information on how to use the REST routing service with Bing Maps V7 can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427607.aspx

The Bing Maps V8 map control was just released as a public preview a couple weeks ago. The directions module in there will support the ability to provide future date/times.